# Как сделать закругленные кнопки Delphi Embarcadero

Tags: delphi

По какой-то причине стандартные TButton помещаются на форму в виде прямоугольной формы, хотя в интернете сказано, что они должны быть с закругленными краями. В чем проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведи источник, где сказано о закругленных краях. Добавь версию delphi и какой проект создаешь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте VCL стили. Меню->Project options->Application->Appearance
Может что и найдёте для себя красивое.

Comment: Да, я этим и воспользовался, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Windows сам рисует Buttons, поэтому в Windows 10 кнопки с прямыми углами, а в 11 - с закруглёнными. Если очень нужно, можно поискать какие-нибудь сторонние компоненты кнопок.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).